# How to convert date into timestamp in SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to migrate data from **old_table** to **new_table**, but in old table the date datatype is **datetime** and in new table the date datatype is **int** and is accepting timestamp value.

So how to convert the old date in sql query so that it get inserted in new table as timestamp?

```
INSERT INTO `new_table` (`id`, `user_id`, `doctor_id`, `message_id`, `type`, `is_message`, `is_note`, `doctor_initials`, `call_status`, `message`, `date_created`, `date_updated`, `day`)
  SELECT id, usid, drid, message_id, type, is_message, is_note, doctor, kall, message, datein, 123, ziua
  FROM `old_table`;
```

I want a function which convert old date to value to timestamp e.g in the above query **CONVERT_INTO_TIMESTAMP(datein)**

Any help will be highly appreciated.

New Table **date_created** field accepts values in unix timestamp such as : **1540642765**

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The function you are looking for is `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`, e.g.

```
select UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1970-01-01 00:00:00');
```

gives 0 in the UTC timezone.

Answer (score 3):

Try [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function:

```
INSERT INTO `new_table`
            (`id`,
             `user_id`,
             `doctor_id`,
             `message_id`,
             `type`,
             `is_message`,
             `is_note`,
             `doctor_initials`,
             `call_status`,
             `message`,
             `date_created`,
             `date_updated`,
             `day`)
SELECT id,
       usid,
       drid,
       message_id,
       type,
       is_message,
       is_note,
       doctor,
       kall,
       message,
       Unix_timestamp(datein),
       '123',
       ziua
FROM   `old_table`;
```

From Docs:

> If called with no argument, returns a Unix timestamp (seconds since
>   '1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC) as an unsigned integer. If UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
>   is called with a date argument, it returns the value of the argument
>   as seconds since '1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC. The date argument may be a
>   DATE, DATETIME, or TIMESTAMP string, or a number in YYMMDD,
>   YYMMDDHHMMSS, YYYYMMDD, or YYYYMMDDHHMMSS format. The server
>   interprets date as a value in the current time zone and converts it to
>   an internal value in UTC.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT date_part('epoch', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)::int;
```

Answer (score 0):

since this question is also tagged for SQL
people who came here for timestamp solution in SQL/MSSQL Query. can try below

```
SELECT CAST(DueDate AS TIMESTAMP) "NewDueDate"
```

where `DueDate` is column with having date like - `YYYY-MM-DD HH:ii:ss` .
if your column is in type varchar then still above syntax will work fine.